# How to add Target property to a new MouseEvent?

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, dom-events

I'm trying to dispatch a `contextMenu` event and have noticed that in the `MouseEvent; interface for TypeScript there isn't a`target` property which is in the [documentation of contextMenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu#Properties).

my TS snippet

```
const emulatedMouseEvent: MouseEvent = new MouseEvent('contextmenu', {
  bubbles: true,
  altKey: event.args[0],
  ctrlKey: event.args[1],
  shiftKey: event.args[2]
})
this.webview.dispatchEvent(emulatedMouseEvent)
```

TS Error when trying to add `target: event.args[3]`

```
Argument of type '{ bubbles: true; altKey: any; ctrlKey: any; shiftKey: any; target: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEventInit'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'target' does not exist in type 'MouseEventInit'.ts(2345)
```

and in lib.dom.d.ts

```
interface MouseEvent extends UIEvent {
    readonly altKey: boolean;
    readonly button: number;
    readonly buttons: number;
    readonly clientX: number;
    readonly clientY: number;
    readonly ctrlKey: boolean;
    /** @deprecated */
    readonly fromElement: Element;
    readonly layerX: number;
    readonly layerY: number;
    readonly metaKey: boolean;
    readonly movementX: number;
    readonly movementY: number;
    readonly offsetX: number;
    readonly offsetY: number;
    readonly pageX: number;
    readonly pageY: number;
    readonly relatedTarget: EventTarget;
    readonly screenX: number;
    readonly screenY: number;
    readonly shiftKey: boolean;
    /** @deprecated */
    readonly toElement: Element;
    /** @deprecated */
    readonly which: number;
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;
    getModifierState(keyArg: string): boolean;
    initMouseEvent(typeArg: string, canBubbleArg: boolean, cancelableArg: boolean, viewArg: Window, detailArg: number, screenXArg: number, screenYArg: number, clientXArg: number, clientYArg: number, ctrlKeyArg: boolean, altKeyArg: boolean, shiftKeyArg: boolean, metaKeyArg: boolean, buttonArg: number, relatedTargetArg: EventTarget | null): void;
}

declare var MouseEvent: {
    prototype: MouseEvent;
    new(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: MouseEventInit): MouseEvent;
};
```

of course in [the MouseEvent documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Properties) there isn't a `Target` property but I don't know how I'm supposed to create this `contextmenu` event with the target property which does exist on the event itself but not on MouseEvent of course.

**Edit:** not a duplicate, that question deals with Target being returned null and the solution does not suffice for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set target property when simulating mouseclick in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108094/how-to-set-target-property-when-simulating-mouseclick-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue where I needed to create events with `target` set because an underlying library relied on it, I worked around it by creating a function that accepts `MouseEventInit & { target: EventTarget }`

```
function mouseEvent(event: string, args: MouseEventInit & { target: EventTarget }): MouseEvent {
  return new MouseEvent(event, { bubbles: true, ...args });
}
```

You can then call `mouseEvent('contextmenu', { target })` instead of `new MouseEvent()`

Answer (score -2):

`MouseEvent extends UIEvent`, `UIEvent extends Event`, Event has [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property.

Comment: Check the edit to the post, the MouseEventInit does not have that property.

Comment: Check the first answer in that question. `MouseEvent.target` cannot be specified during creation, it is automatically set to the element the created event is dispatched on.